# Unable to create symlink in laravel 6.9.0 shared hosting deployment

Tags: laravel, deployment, symlink, shared-hosting, laravel-6

[image: Empty response]Symlinks are basically shortcuts to individual files or folders. My project(website) needs one mandatory symlink creation. Details of target folder and link folder:

target folder: `/home/domainname/stream/storage/app/public/blogs`

link folder: `/home/domainanme/public_html/storage`

Basically a symlink would create clone of blogs folder and its content from target folder to a link folder.

I tried three approaches to overcome this exact issue:

1. Created `symlink.php` file inside public_html folder, coded it to create exact symlink as described above and ran that php file (`symlink.php`) in browser (`domainname.com/symlink`).
2. Somewhere in the web, I found cron jobs would also do the job. So I created one.
3. Created `/createsymlink` route where artisan command (`storage:link`) exists, ran the url in browser (`domainname.com/createsymlink`)

All three measures did not help creating symlink.

This part is so important for my project because without this I cannot manipulate single images in my website.

Note:

1. I am not using ssh
2. Browsing `domainname.com/symlink.php` does not echo anything.

```
Project tree sample:
-domainname
   -stream (main project folder)
   -public_html (contains public folder from main project folder)
```

All other features function

//Code

```
//Cron job
ln -s /home/domainname/stream/storage/app/public/blogs /home/domainname/public_html/
```

```
//symlink.php
<?php
$target = '/home/domainname/stream/storage/app/public/blogs';
$link = '/home/domainname/public_html/storage';
symlink($target, $link);
echo readlink($link);
?>
```

```
//Route symlink
Route::get('/createsymlink', function () {
   Artisan::call('storage:link');
   return "success";
});
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you aren't misspelling `storage` as `strorage` right?

Comment: Nope that happened here only

Comment: Do you have permissions to make symlinks on the host machine? Would it be possible for you to get ssh access? What does the `symlink()` in `symlink.php` return? It [should return true on success](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php).

Comment: One awkward thing in my public_html folder I noticed which might not affect this cause at all but not taking a chance:  Initially there was logs folder when deploying, now the logs folder has been changed/renamed to E:\work\bla\stream\storage\logs(local path)

Comment: Ok I see a problem here but I dont know how: Code inside symlink.php is updated above and I get blank page on load.

Comment: I did a little mistake in link path. I had coded to store images in storage/blogs and here I just assigned storage in link path. So I was not getting images in the website. Another thing symlink was totally hidden inside the public_html folder, I had no access to set hidden items visible which literally scewed up my precious time. The symlink is now created and it is working all fine. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In shared hosting it's better to use cron job.

Please delete your storage folder from /public and then create cron job by using the bellow code:

ln -s /home/domainname/stream/storage/app/public/ /home/domainname/stream/storage/app/public/storage